# How to import data to Dataset and retrain custom model in Google Cloud AutoML

Tags: c#, rest, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm a new developer with GCP and I learn about Google Cloud AutoML Custom Model. but I have 2 problems with AutoML Vision.

**1. I can't import data from csv file in cloud storage to Dataset.
I'm using C# to call RestAPI but its error 404. below is my code.**

```
var uri = "https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project-id}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{dataset-id}:import";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"inputUris\":\"gs://{bucket-name}/Vehicles/csv/{csv-file-name}.csv\"}";
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

**2. How cant i Retrain Custom Model using C# or RestAPI**

For example: the user uploads a new image of something with a label for that image. then create a csv file and upload to cloud storage. So I would like import Dataset using that csv file then retrain custom model only the image inside csv file (Add new image training to old model).

Answer (score 2):

In adition to @Awais answer, 
The correct call api is

```
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{id-project}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{id-dataset}:importData
```

and the correct json format payload for this function is

```
{
    "inputConfig": {
        "gcsSource": {
            "inputUris": [
                "gs://my-bucket-vcm/uploads/app/csv/19_03_2019_18_16_35.csv"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets/importData)

Answer (score 0):

Answer of question 1:
I suggest you to re-check the csv file, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#csv) 
Example:

```
gs://my-project-lcm/training-data/file1.txt,Sports,Basketball
gs://my-project-lcm/training-data/ubuntu.zip,Computers,Software,Operating_Systems,Linux,Ubuntu
file://news/documents/file2.txt,Sports,Baseball
"Miles Davis was an American jazz trumpeter, bandleader, and composer.",Arts_Entertainment,Music,Jazz
TRAIN,gs://my-project-lcm/training-data/astros.txt,Sports,Baseball
VALIDATE,gs://my-project-lcm/training-data/mariners.txt,Sports,Baseball
TEST,gs://my-project-lcm/training-data/cubs.txt,Sports,Baseball
```

Answer of question 2:
I think that when you retrain your dataset (with new images), it will create a new model using all datset (with new images).
If you look at the list of models, you will see that you will have 2 models and a dataset.

This is the curl to use if you want to import the dataset:

```
curl 
  -X POST 
  -H "Authorization: Bearer here-access-token" 
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{id-project}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{id-dataset}:import \
  -d '{
    "inputUris": "gs://name-bucket-vcm/csv/file-csv.csv",
  }'
```

Here is python code:

```
import requests

url = "https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{id-project}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{id-dataset}:import"

payload = "{"inputUris": "gs://bucket-vcm/csv/file-csv.csv"}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Answer 1: not working,
This is my csv file " TRAIN,gs://bucket-name/Vehicles/images/Other-001.jpg,Other ",
This is my error " The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: I tried to import images to dataset on AutoML Vision UI by using this uri "gs://{bucket-name}/Vehicles/csv/{csv-file-name}.csv" it working

Comment: try to import dataset via cURL

Comment: I'm using cygwin on windows, below is output
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer my-token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/datasets/dataset-id:import -d '{"inputUris": "gs://budget-name/Vehicles/csv/file-name.csv"}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: automl.googleapis.com

Comment: and using gcloud shell, below is the output

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/datasets/dataset-id:import -d '{"inputUris": "gs://budget-name/Vehicles/csv/file-name.csv"}'

Comment: <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/datasets/dataset-id:import</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

Comment: very strange, check if your access_token and uri it's right or no.

Comment: also check if your service account has all access, check this guide and repeat all points  https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin

Comment: Thank you , I will check again, but I can listing dataset, predict and train the model  using RestAPI and curl, but import data isn't working

Comment: I only used curl to import datasets and i've already passed you the code

Comment: Are you working on AutoML Vision or AutoML Natural Language?

Comment: on automl vision

Comment: OK, Thank you @Awais

Comment: I hope I have been helpful, @Vixar