# automl import data to dataset List of found errors: 1.Field: name; Message: Required field is invalid

Tags: angular, rest, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am using gapi to access google autoML api. I managed to create a new dataset, but having difficultly importing data to it.

```
List of found errors:   1.Field: name; Message: Required field is invalid
```

I am following the guide from google automl, but they have not mentioned about the field name.
https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.datasets/importData

Anyone has successfully using the api and share me the solution?

```
    importCSVtoDataset() {
    let projectId = 'projectID';
    let serverLocation = 'us-central1';
    let datasetName = 'dataset1';
    let url = `https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${projectId}/locations/${serverLocation}/datasets/${datasetName}:importData`;
    let videoData = {
        name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${serverLocation}/datasets/${datasetName}`,
        inputConfig: {
            gcsSource: {
              inputUris: [
                  'gs://reconnaitre-drone-os-vcm/uploads/csv/uploadthis_csv.csv'
              ]
            }
        }
    }
    this.afAuth.authenticateGoogleAPI().then(() => {
      return gapi.client.request({
              // Pick an endpoint based on the scope and api you defined.
              path: url,
              method: 'POST',
              body: videoData,
            })
            .then(result => {
                  console.log("result from GET",result.body)
                })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to this post. the datasetName should be dataset ID, instead of the display name.

[How to import data to Dataset and retrain custom model in Google Cloud AutoML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638410/how-to-import-data-to-dataset-and-retrain-custom-model-in-google-cloud-automl)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoML, in the request.json file you need to use the import_schema_uri video_OBJECTIVE_io_format_1.0.0.yaml instead of automl_video_OBJECTIVE_io_format_1.0.0.yaml. On this page, https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/video-data/classification/prepare-data?authuser=1 it says to use this file path. Perhaps try following their format at the link.

```
{
  "import_configs": [
    {
      "gcs_source": {
        "uris": "IMPORT_FILE_URI"
      },
     "import_schema_uri" : "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/video_OBJECTIVE_io_format_1.0.0.yaml"
    }
  ]
}
```